# Why is countDocuments function in mongoose not reading a variable I put in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a list called `collectionList`, and I am wanting to go through the object list and see if a document in my mongodb collection exists. If it doesn't exist, then it will create a new document for that list item. The new document `name` should be the same as the `name` in the object list.

Here is the list:

```
const collectionList = [
    { name: "pages", schema: pageSchema.pageSchema },
    { name: "posts", schema: postSchema.postSchema }
]
```

If there is not a document with the `name` equal to the `collectionList[i].name`, then I want mongoose to create a new document with the `name`.

Here is the section of the code that the bug is occurring in:

```
for (var i = 0; i < collectionList.length; i++) {
    var collectionName = collectionList[i].name
    console.log("collectionList name:",collectionName); // Outputs the collectionList[i].name to make sure it is working
    Collection.countDocuments({ name: collectionName })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            if (data == null || data == 0 || data == false) {
                const newCollection = new Collection({
                    name: collectionName,
                    data: []
                })
                newCollection.save().then(() => {
                    console.log('collection saved', collectionName)
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            } else {
                console.log("I found it, but I don't know what to do!")

            }

        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}
```

My mongodb collection is called `Collection` and it is empty, there are no documents in it. When I run it, it console logs `collectionList name: pages` then `collectionList name: posts` on line 3. When I look in my mongodb collection, the `name` in both document is `posts`. Why is it not creating the document with the `name: pages`? On line 13 when I console log the `collectionName`, both times it logs `posts`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: I just needed to add `await`. It wasn't executing in the right order. Thank you though.

Comment: It's worth while to understand why `collectionName` changes in the loop when using `var`, the await just masks that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just correction and opinion:

its a bit confused to use `await` and `then` in the same time. `then` its already promise. and please check the conditional `if (data == null || data == 0 || data == false) {` . use `if(data)` instead.

following your description, you just need to use `findAndUpdate`, reff [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate)

*`if data not exist, then create a new one`.*

that would be like:

```js
const collectionList = [
    { name: "pages", schema: pageSchema.pageSchema },
    { name: "posts", schema: postSchema.postSchema }
]

const newCollection = new Collection()
for (const key of collectionList) {
    await newCollection.findOneAndUpdate({name: key.name}, {name: key.name}, {upsert:true})
}
```

or you can use [BulkWrite](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-bulkWrite) and `updateOne` for better approach

that would be like:

```js
const collectionList = [
    { name: "pages", schema: pageSchema.pageSchema },
    { name: "posts", schema: postSchema.postSchema }
]

const data = collectionList.map(el => {
    return {
        updateOne: {
            filter: { name: el.name },
            update: { name: el.name },
            options: { upsert: true }
        }
    }
})

const res = await newCollection.bulkWrite(data);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just needed to add `await` before the `Collection.countDocuments({ name: collectionName })`. Like this:
`await Collection.countDocuments({ name: collectionName })`.